# How to get all the SEQUENCES GRANT DDL for the SCHEMA in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sequence

Tried below query to get the sequence's privileges,

```
select * from dba_tab_privs where owner='TEST' and TYPE='SEQUENCE';
```

Response:

```
GRANTEE      OWNER  TABLE_NAME  GRANTOR PRIVILEGE   GRANTABLE   HIERARCHY   COMMON  TYPE    INHERITED

READ_WRITE   TEST   TEST_SEQ    TEST    SELECT       NO         NO            NO    SEQUENCE    NO
```

But how do i get the DDL of this as below?

```
grant select on TEST.TEST_SEQ to READ_WRITE;
```

I have tried to get the DDL of sequences using below query though,

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, owner) || ';' AS object_ddl
FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OWNER = 'TEST' AND OBJECT_TYPE IN ('SEQUENCE')
ORDER BY OWNER, OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to look at the the DDL, you can generate the statement from what you already have by concatenating the column values together:

```
select 'GRANT ' || privilege || ' ON "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '" TO "' || grantee || '";'
from dba_tab_privs where owner='TEST' and TYPE='SEQUENCE';
```

You may not need the double-quotes but I generally include them just in case you have any quoted identifiers lurking in your database.

If you really want to use `dbms_metadata` then you need the `get_dependent_ddl` function instead of `get_ddl`:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', table_name, owner)
from dba_tab_privs where owner='TEST' and type='SEQUENCE';
```

which will give similarly-quoted identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The correct call is:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT','TEST','TEST_SEQ') from dual
```

You can also easily script it yourself:

```
SELECT 'GRANT '||privilege||' ON "'||owner||'"."'||table_name||'" TO "'||grantee||'";'
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE (owner,table_name) IN (SELECT sequence_owner,sequence_name
                                FROM dba_sequences
                               WHERE sequence_owner = 'TEST')
```